# Ruby - Mechanize: get() throws exception

Tags: ruby, parsing, mechanize, cloudflare

I want to parse site protected by CloudFlare.
And last line in this block:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
refs = agent.get(site).links_with(text: 'test')
```

throws exception and here's output:

```
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:308:in 'fetch': 503 => Net::HTTPServiceUnvailable for <site> - unhandled response (Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)
    from c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:440:in 'get'
    from script.rb:10:in '<main>'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I found this python module: https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape. But I don't know python and can't implement the same functional on ruby by my own.

Comment: What's `site`? The server didn't like your request, maybe you need to set `user_agent` or some other header

Comment: I got one thing - mechanize can't work with js. Can I somehow resolve it?

Comment: That's not the problem, something about the request is causing the 503. Try my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to contact the site owner to see if they will whitelist your IPs. What you're doing might look like an attack & a security feature is being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory:

```
Net::HTTPServiceUnvailable
```

means that the site is unavailable, it is not about your code, the problem is in the site itself.

edit: you can use [watir](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Tutorial)

Comment: Site is available. But it uses CloudFlare - DDoS protection system. If you using internet browser, this system will check something (cookies, I think). So how can I simulate usual browser behavior?

Comment: @EdAkhmetshin try a gem called Watir

Comment: Gem is interesting, thank you. But I need something, that will be more suitable for parsing.

Comment: @EdAkhmetshin after opening your site with watir, it is possible to parse it with any gem such as nokogiri. Here is a quick tutorial to get you started http://www.layeredthoughts.com/automation/how-to-write-your-first-ruby-web-bot-in-watir-scraping-weather-com

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple and practical solution. Open the website protected by Cloudflare in your browser and copy your user-agent string and the value of the `cf_clearance` cookie.

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent = '<YOUR_USER_AGENT_STRING>'
# Add a cookie to pass Cloudflare protection
agent.cookie_jar << HTTP::Cookie.new(
  'cf_clearance', '<CF_CLEARANCE_VALUE>', domain: '.<DOMAIN>', path: '/'
)
page = agent.get('https://<PROTECTED_WEBSITE>')
puts 'YAY!'
```